# How do I return paginated code with only short page info?

Tags: java, spring, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I am using Hibernate, JPA and Spring and I want to return a json with loans paginated. I want the page info to be simple and have only the page, size and total like the following:

```
{
  "items":[
    {
      “id”: 1,
      “total”: 2500.00
      “user_id”: 1
    },
    {
      “id”: 2,
      “total”: 65120.75
      “user_id”: 1
    }
  ],
  "paging":{
    "page": 1,
    "size": 50,
    "total": 1500
  }
 }
```

I have a JPA repository for loans.

This is how my controller looks like right now:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/loans")
public class LoansController {

@Autowired
private UserLoansRepository loansRep;

@GetMapping(params = { "page", "size" })
public Page<UserLoansEntity> findPaginated(@RequestParam("page") int page,
                             @RequestParam("size") int size) {

    Pageable pages = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    Page<UserLoansEntity> resultPage = loansRep.findAll(pages);

    return resultPage;
}
}
```

I am getting this instead:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "idLoan": 10,
            "total": 222
        },
        {
            "idLoan": 11,
            "total": 3333
        },
        {
            "idLoan": 12,
            "total": 3333.33
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "pageSize": 3,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "totalElements": 5,
    "first": true,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 3,
    "size": 3,
    "number": 0,
    "empty": false
}
```

Any help?

Comment: If Stack Overflow asks for proper explanation it's for a reason. Adding nonsense phrases just to meet the minimum character rule doesn't help no one! :)

Answer (score 2):

It would probably help if you map the entity to a DTO object that you can return from the API.

You could map the properties manually or use an object mapping library (such as Orika, Jackson). Just to give you a rough idea:

```java
PageDto pageDto = new PageDto();
pageDto.setPage(resultPage.getPageable().getPageSize());
pageDto.setSize(resultPage.getPageable().getPageNumber() + 1);
pageDto.setTotal(resultPage.getTotalElements());

pagedResponseDto.setPaging(pageDto);
pagedResponseDto.setItems(pageDto.getContent());
```

where, `PageDto` and `PagedResponseDto` are (roughly):

```java
class PageDto {

  private Integer page;
  private Integer size;
  private Integer total;
}
```

```java
class PagedResponseDto<T> {

  private List<T> items;
  private PageDto pageDto;
}
```

Not only will that help you achieve your goal, it's also a good practice to keep the beans in the API layer decoupled from the domain representation.

Comment: this PageDto class from which  library is?

Comment: It's not from a library. It's a custom object that you can create. I'll edit the answer to include a likely implementation.